# How to do a minimal install using Bower

Tags: jquery, bower, bower-install

I'm using Bower to manage all the front end libraries and tools I'm using for a project.  My `bower.json` file looks like this

```
{
  "name": "New Project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "~1.11.1",
    "bootstrap": "~3.3.4"
  }
}
```

When I run `bower install` it creates a `jquery/src` directory with a ton of JS files that I don't need and won't use.  I just need the `jquery.min.js` file.  Is there a way to control how much is installed and just do a minimal install?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bower.json install only single file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25557669/bower-json-install-only-single-file)

Answer (score 0):

Only Grab the Files You Need While Using Bower

links:

1. explanation: https://scotch.io/tutorials/only-grab-the-files-you-need-while-using-bower
2. direct: https://github.com/blittle/bower-installer

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: All links are broken.